# Where are feature changes to StackExchange announced?

Tags: discussion, sffaq

This was answered in a comment by Robert Cartaino, I wanted to repeat it in an easier-to-find location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments on a question about the new answer votes, Robert Cartaino said:

> The dedicated site for announcements
>   is the blog:  blog.stackexchange.com.
>
> If that does not provide enough
>   detail, there is a "Recent Feature
>   Changes" list:
>   [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)
>
> Beyond that lies meta.Stackoverflow,
>   which gets into the really
>   nitty-gritty, insider-baseball stuff.
>
> Three resources to pick from,
>   depending on your level of interest in
>   this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still astonished that it should even be needed. One would think such information would be made more obvious and MUCH easier to find. I wonder why it's not even mentioned in the FAQ.

Comment: I'm guessing that only the meta-users would be remotely interested, and we're probably a small percentage. Most likely just pop onto the site for help/entertainment. Though it does make me wonder.